# Filter the data from the return of HTTP Call - Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http-get, angular-filters

I am creating a project which uses a HTTP get from a web service and returns an array of projects, with ID, name, description etc.

Previously, before I created my filter, the get returned a list of 60 elements using an ngFor in the HTML file: 
[image]

There is many projects within this web service but I am only concerned with 9 of them the rest are irrelevant.

My code was working when I had created my own observable object with manual data:  in my project.service.http.ts class:

```
data: Project[] = [
    {
id:...,
name:...
etc
    },
```

and then in the fetchProjects Method:

```
fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return Observable.of(this.data);
  }
```

Because I want the observable object to be the data from my http get, this method is void. I tried to implement the observable being returned as the data from the web service, but I get the error below in my console when running.
Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: response.filter is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._next (project.viewer.component.ts:36)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/operator/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
```

My Code:

project.service.http.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectServiceHttp extends ProjectService {

    //variables
    baseUrl = "";

    static projectIds: string[] = ["","","","","",""
                            ,"", "",""];

    //constructor
   constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
    }

    //methods
    fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]>{
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
          .map((response: Response) => 
          {
            let result = response.json();
            return Observable.of(result);
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
        }

}
```

project.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'project-viewer',
    templateUrl: './project-viewer.html',  
    styleUrls: ['./project-viewer.css']
})

export class ProjectViewerComponent  {
    name = 'ProjectViewerComponent';
    projects: Project[] = [];
    static projectIds: string[] = ["",""
    ,"","","",""
    ,"", "",""];
    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;

    constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(response => {
          this.projects = response.filter(elements => {
            return ProjectViewerComponent.projectIds.includes(elements.id);
          });
        })
      }

    private fetchProjects() {
        this.service
            .fetchProjects()
            .subscribe(response =>{
              this.projects = response['project']
              .filter(project => { return  ['...', '','','','','...'
              ,'','',''].indexOf(project.id) !== -1})
              console.log(response);
              console.log(this.projects);
            },
            errors=>{
               console.log(errors);
            });
    }

}
```

project-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Projects </h3>
<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let project of projects" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module project" >
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{project.name}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

They are multiple error in your project. First of all in your service you are not using correctly the map operator you should do:

```
//methods
fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]>{
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
      .map(response => response.json())
}
```

Then in the component you subscribe to the service then you try to do the filtering. You can do that before subscribe like this:

```
private fetchProjects() {
    const filterProject = ['TotalMobileAnalyseInsights', 'TotalMobileMendel','TotalMobileSlam','TotalMobileServer','TotalMobileWedAdmin','TotalMobileForAndroid'
              ,'TotalMobileForWindows','TotalMobileForWindowsUniversal','TotalMobileForIOS'];
    this.service.fetchProjects()
       // convert each element of the array into a single observable
       .flatMap(projects => ArrayObservable.create(projects))
       // filter project
       .filter(project => filterProject.indexOf(project.id) !== -1)
       .toArray()
       // subscribe and do something with the project
       .subscribe(projects => console.log(projects));
}
```

Here is a quick running example https://plnkr.co/edit/3nzr3CFhV2y0iu3cQwAF?p=preview

Comment: what about in the constructor of the component?

Comment: Errors in your code: Property 'fromArray' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. 

and Cannot find name 'filterProject'.

and 
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'

Comment: and in the constructor of the component do what?? you are missing that code for your solution. I implemented code above and now no errors but no projects are displayed - nothing in console

Comment: do you call the fetchProjects in your component ? Constructor seems to do what fetchProjects.

Comment: my component constructor : 
 constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.fetchProjects();
       
      }